# Model is null from Json object

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So when I set the javascript ReminderModel object properties this will work and my controller will receive the object if I set `LeadId` and `StaffId` to 1, but as soon as I turn them into strings the controller receives a null object.

I'm not sure what's going on, it might be a problem with the quotes?

My view code

```
var ReminderModel = {
                        "LeadId": "@Model.Id",
                        "StaffId": "1a53c286-b17e-4afd-9ccb-684fd1a92f7b",
                        "Subject": "Call Back",
                        "Time": "iTime",
                        "Date": "iDate"
                    };


                    $.ajax({
                        url: "@Url.Action("SetReminder","Appointment")",
                        type: 'POST',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: JSON.stringify(ReminderModel),
                        success: function (valid) {
                            if (valid) {
                                //show that id is valid
                            } else {
                                //show that id is not valid
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

My controller Method

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> SetReminder([FromBody] ReminderViewModel viewModel)
        {

            using (var db = new LeadCoreDbContext())
            {
                DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
                DateTime.TryParse($"{viewModel.Date} {viewModel.Time}", out dt);

                if (dt == DateTime.MinValue)
                    throw new Exception("Failed to set reminder");

                var reminder = new Reminder
                {
                    Deleted = false,
                    LeadId = viewModel.LeadId,
                    Subject = viewModel.Subject,
                    TimeToRemind = dt,
                    StaffId = viewModel.StaffId
                };

                db.Reminder.Add(reminder);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            }

            return Content("received");
        }
```

Here is the model

```
public class ReminderViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public int StaffId { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please show the declaration of `ReminderViewModel `

Comment: @NineBerry I forgot that, it's edited now.

Comment: LeadViewModel  != ReminderViewModel

Comment: 1: Like NineBarry said, you've posted the wrong model. 2: Have you done it without stringifying the obejct in your POST?

Comment: @NineBerry sorry, it's easy to make mistakes when you got a wife nagging you to go somewhere while you're trying to post. Edited.

Comment: LeadID and StaffID are integers in the model. So, you need to supply integers in the json, not strings.

Comment: @NineBerry yeah that fixed it, post it as an answer and I'll except that, can't believe I overlooked that for half an hour.